# Cannot call all functions on UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop

I am trying to transform a `UIWebView` on iOS with `setTransform` and I also try to hide it with `setHidden`.

These functions both don't work in the current setup but `loadRequest` does; why is this the case and how can I get `setTransform` and `setHidden` to work?

```
// ViewController.h
@class EAGLView, ARUtils;
@interface ViewController : ARViewController {
    UIWebView* webview;
}
@property (assign) UIWebView* webview;

// ViewController.mm
@synthesize webview;

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    webview = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]] autorelease];
    [self.view addSubview:webview];
}

// EAGLView.mm
ViewController* uic;
for( UIView* next = [self superview];  next; next = next.superview){
    UIResponder* nextResponder = [next nextResponder];
    if([nextResponder isKindOfClass:[ViewController class]]){
        uic = (ViewController*)nextResponder;
    }
}

// These functions don't work:
[[[uic webview] layer] setTransform:matrix];
[[uic webview] setHidden:YES];

// And this one does:
[[uic webview] loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that `webview` isn't `nil` when you set the transform?

Comment: Yes because I can call the function `[[uic webview] loadRequest:requestObj];` and that one works fine, it gets displayed on the screen but not transformed.

Comment: Where are you calling these methods exactly? Is it possible that you're on a background thread?

Comment: I am calling these functions inside the `renderFrameQCAR` function from the Vuforia framework. I don't really know how Vuforia handles it's threads. `EAGLView` is an extension of `AR_EAGLView`, this is the source of that class: https://github.com/pkjmesra/VuforiaAugmentedReality/blob/master/ARCommon/AR_EAGLView.mm

Comment: You could check `[NSThread isMainThread]`...

Comment: That functions returns `0` so I guess it is indeed on a background thread. But why does one function work and the others don't?

Comment: You have to be on the main thread/queue when you're using any UIKit classes. It's possible of course that some things also "happen to" work from a background thread, but there's no guarantee. Use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ //your code here });`

Comment: Thank you very very much, that worked and now I know the problem. If you create an answer I'll accept it and upvote it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most UIKit classes (like `UIWebView`) are only safe to use from the main thread. When you're on a background thread, you can use GCD to perform a block on the main queue (which is associated with the main thread):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you import correctly QuartzCore header ? I sometimes wonder why my code doesn't work, then I realize i forgot to import this header..

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Edit :

Can you try this code, which works with Layer-Backed view :

```
CATransform3D matrix = CATransform3DRotate(web.layer.transform, 1.14, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

CABasicAnimation *animTransform = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
animTransform.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:web.layer.transform];
animTransform.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D: matrix];

animTransform.duration = 1;  // arbitrary chosen time
animTransform.autoreverses = NO; // we don't want animation to go back from beginning when ended
animTransform.repeatCount = 0;
animTransform.delegate=self;  // optional, you can use a delegate to start methods when the animation ends


// real change of the values, because the CABasicAnimation is only visual
web.layer.transform = aTransform;

// and start the animation
[web.layer  addAnimation:animTransform forKey:nil];
```

You can find very useful information about animation (and layer-backed // layer-hosted view) here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH3-SW1

Comment: Yeah I already did that, I had that problem too but at least that one gave me an error...

Comment: Are you working with layer-backed view ? If so, you cannot directly access the transform attribute.

Comment: Mmm I don't really know that, I am really new to Objective-C; but I updated my question with more information.

Comment: Oh i just saw that, you should add : 
[webview setWantsLayer:YES] 

Then you can use layers and core animation with your view

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work, also the call `web.layer.transform = aTransform` generates an error. And `[webview setWantsLayer:YES]` also doesn't work because webview doesn't have a function/property called `setWantsLayer`.

Comment: web.layer.transform = aTransform; is a wrong copy-paste, my bad
web.layer.transform = animTransform; should work instead

for the setWantsLayer: method, it comes from OSX, i work on both and sometimes got messy.

try :
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];[animationDuration = 1.0]; view.layer.transform = matrix; [UIView commitAnimations];

Comment: did you try with : [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];[animationDuration = 1.0]; view.layer.transform = matrix; [UIView commitAnimations]; ?

Comment: Well i don't know why it doesn't work, it's fine for me :/
Maybe you missed something in the initialization of the layer? You should check the Apple doc i linked, it's rally useful.
Good luck !

Comment: Layer-backed views are only relevant on OS X (`NSView`, not `UIView`), every view on iOS has a layer associated with it (on OS X, this would be called "layer-hosting view").

Comment: Yeah I also checked that out, I don't really understand what is causing this but thanks for the effort anyway!